# How to detect if user has switched Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A user logs into my application in a tab in a browser

They get an email and click a link which opens a new tab in the same browser and logs them in under a different email say.

If they go back to the first tab they are no longer the same user and I want the page to automatically detect this and then reload or redirect them if they are unauthorized to view the page.

Anyway to do this?

Comment: add javascript code to reload page periodically (for example once per 30 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, if you really want to know when user is switched the tab, try this library:

[visibility.js](https://github.com/evilmartians/visibility.js)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and suggestions. I will give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Hck:
add javascript code to reload page periodically (for example once per 30 seconds) – Hck

JavaScript is pretty much the only way to make pages do stuff after they're loaded. Note that in pretty much any user authentication system, a given browser will only be logged in as one user at a time, so as soon as the second tab opens, that browser will be acting as the second user - they can still see the current content of the first tab, but links (for instance) will no longer work unless the second user was also authorized to use them.
There are some JQuery plugins that do this sort of thing, like [PeriodicalUpdater](https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/), or you can write your own ([an example](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2009/02/26/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/)).